# Digest Authentication with HttpWebRequest

Tags: .net, digest-authentication

I am looking for a specific example for using Digest Authentication with HttpWebRequest.
For doing DigestAuthentication, I create the NetworkCredential using the username/password and domain.

Then I set the Credentials property on the HttpWebRequest.

My question is what is required to indicate to the HttpWebRequest that it is a Digest Authentication.

I am looking for specific example of making an HttpWebRequest using Digest authentication scheme.
In all the samples, I see that a NetworkCredential is created and then added to the CredentialCache.

But there is no indication on how HttpWeqRequest does the Digest Authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

httpwebrequest made the request to the server with digest authentication by adding the cache to its credential where the authentication type of the cache is specified by Digest
like:

```
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.add(new uri("your url"), "Digest", New NetworkCredential("username", "Password", "domain"));
request.Credential = cache;
```